# Array from BASH, index from AWK

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

Is there any possibility to get value from BASH array using index defined in AWK?

```
Bash:
table=(a b c d e)
instructions | awk " BEGIN {index=0} {print \"${table[**index**]}\"; index++} "
```

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us how to implement something that you shouldn't be doing. I recommend you post a different question asking how to do whatever the text transformation is that you are attempting, including sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this but why?

```
table=(a b c d e); awk -vt="${table[*]}" 'BEGIN{n=split(t,a," "); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i]}'

a
b
c
d
e
```

you can do the array element access in bash directly as well.

Comment: Won't preserve embedded spaces in array elements.